# Event id is nil

Tags: ruby-on-rails, model-view-controller, link-to

I am trying to connect my pages so that the user has a show page and once they get to the show page they see events. The Event can also be clicked on and once that event is clicked on it goes directly to that events show page. The error I am getting is

```
No route matches {:action=>"show", :controller=>"events", :id=>nil}
```

Here is what my events form looks like:

```
<span class="name">EventName: <%= link_to(event.name, controller: "events", action: "show", id: @event) %></span>
<span class="partycode">PartyCode:<br><%= event.partycode %></span>
```

Here is my Events controller:

```
class EventsController < ApplicationController
    def show
        @event = Event.find(params[:id])
    end

    def create
        @event = current_user.events.build(event_params)
        if @event.save
            flash[:success] = "Event Created!"
            redirect_to root_url
        else
            render 'welcome#index'
        end
    end

    def destroy
    end

    private 

      def event_params
        params.require(:event).permit(:name, :partycode)
      end
end
```

Let me know if you need more code to figure out the problem my error occurs in the events form on the first line. This has been really frustrating because this should be a simple task.

Comment: Normally in a `create` action you do `redirect_to event_path(@event)` or something similar. Arbitrary `render` calls can cause problems.

Comment: How would I redirect back to the users show page(that is where i create the events)

Comment: Sometimes it's worthwhile to pass in a "redirect-to" parameter on your submission form you use to send people back to their originating page. I usually call this parameter `r` for brevity, but you can call it anything you want. Just be sure to put it in the form itself and make sure it stays populated even if there's form errors and you need two tries for the create to succeed.

Comment: I recommend people use `save!` and then rescue from whatever exceptions they're interested in, like `rescue ActiveRecord::RecordInvalid` which can be used to re-present the form and ask for fixes.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try changing

```
<%= link_to(event.name, controller: "events", action: "show", id: @event) %>
```

to

```
<%= link_to(event.name, controller: "events", action: "show", id: event.id) %>
```

(note the missing @) in your template.

Answer (score 1):

What about using the path helpers such as `event_path(@event)`.

Your view would then become:

```
<%= link_to(@event.name, event_path(@event) %>
```